# Determining $\int_0^2 \int_{\frac{x}{2}}^1 e^{x/y} dy dx$

Tags: calculus

I am fairly sure the below equation **requires** me to convert it to polar form, but I am unable to determine the bounds since I don't recognize it as an obvious shape.

$\int_0^2 \int_{\frac{x}{2}}^1 e^{x/y} dy dx$

Is there an easier way to determine this than converting it to polar form? If not how do I determine the new bounds?

I haven't been given any region to evaluate it across, so I feel as though there is something I am missing.

Perhaps I am meant to break the problem up into a group of problems and integrate it component wise?${}{}$

Comment: I don't think $\displaystyle \int e^{\frac{1}{y}} dy$ can be evaluated in elementary functions. See [this](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=Exp%5B1%2Fx%5D&random=false).

Comment: You can exchange the integration order. Integrate $dx$ from $0$ to $2y$ and then integrate $dy$ from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: @ErdosYi I thought that, but was unsure how, given that y = 1, how do I change this bound to x?

Comment: @DisplayName If you look at the region, you have $y = \frac{x}{2}\rightarrow x = 2y$.  So the $x$ would go from $0$ to $2y$ (that does appear to be the way to take this integral).

Comment: @Jared I can see the bound going from $y = \frac{x}{2}$ to $x = 2y$, but when I have $y = 1$ I can't see where this bound goes due to the lack of x I normally have.

Comment: @DisplayName $y$ goes from $0$ to $1$ and $x$ goes from $0$ to $2y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Reverse the order of integration. A diagram will show that we want
$$\int_{y=0}^1 \left(\int_0^{2y}e^{x/y}\,dx\right)\,dy.$$
The inner integral turns out to be very simple.

**Remark:** For me a picture is crucial, I cannot solve the problem without it. Draw the rectangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(2,1)$, and $(0,1)$. Draw the line $y=x/2$. This divides the rectangle into $2$ triangles. Our given integral is over the *upper* triangle. Now the integration first with respect to $x$, then with respect to $y$ writes itself.